# jquery assign object key and value from an array of values

Tags: jquery, arrays, url, object, comparison

okay so im constrcuting a product page and the page has dynamic link creation and i need help linking , im creating every element on the page via jquery append for this reason i cannot create the links with php . so im stuck trying to figure out the differnce between jquery objects and javascript arrays. im trying to grab the url data: 
`?x=wmen&plist=1&s=tops&c=shirts` and check new data against it like : `s=tops&jackets` so i broke everything in the url into small arrays like `['x','wmen'] ,['plist','1'] ...` then did the same for the new data  `['s','tops'] ,['c','shirts'] ...` now i need to compare the two to prevent duplicates, and they are stored in order as they would be if they were clikced like : `?x=wmen&plist=1&s=tops&c=shirts` to be placed in the href.

```
function correctUrl(x){
        var urlArray = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').map(function(val){ return val.split('='); }), newur = [],newurl = {},z=0,arr = 'array'; 
        // push url array into new array
        $.each(urlArray,function(){
            newur.push(this);
        });
        // make array of value
         for (var key in link) {
            var array = arr + z;
            array = [];
            // index at 0 
            array.push(key);
            // value 1
            array.push(link[key]);
            z++;
            newur.push(array);
        }
        for (var i in newur) {
            console.log(newur[i]);
            $.each(newur[i], function(i, el){

            });
        }
        console.log(newurl);

        return x;
    }
```

now here is the problem i have a problem assigning the key and value pair. i want to make the first value the key and the second the value like : `['s','tops'] -> {s:tops}`

Comment: Try `function correctUrl() {
    var obj = {};
    var urlArray = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').each(function (val) {
        var parts = val.split('=');
        obj[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    });
    console.log(obj);

    return $.map(obj, function (val, key) {
        return key = val
    }).join('&');
}`

Comment: this wont work you cannot call the each function this way when targeting an object thats not an dom element.

Comment: it should have been `$.each(location.search.replace('?', '').split('&'), function (val) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i figured it out thanks to some help from @Arun Pjohny the answer was hiding inside the object "key" you cant target array keys because javascript dont have associative arrays but jquery has objects and those objects have keys and with the help of the for loop you can iterate over those objects and get the key and value pair and by rewriting the object key and value pairs you will remove duplicates !!!!!

```
function correctUrl(link){
        var urlArray = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').map(function(val){ return val.split('='); }), newur = [],newurl = {},z=0,arr = 'array',x='?'; 
        // push url array into new array
        for (var i in urlArray){
            $.each(urlArray[i],function(i,el){
                newurl[urlArray[i][0]]/* key */ = urlArray[i][1] ; // value
            });
        }
        // make array of value
         for (var key in link) {
            var array = arr + z;
            array = [];
            // index at 0 
            array.push(key);
            // value 1
            array.push(link[key]);
            z++;
            newur.push(array);
        }
        for (var i in newur) {
            $.each(newur[i], function(i, el){
                newurl[newur[i][0]]/* key */ = newur[i][1] ; // value
            });
        }
        for (var i in newurl){
            x += i+'='+newurl[i]+'&';
        }
        return x.slice(0, - 1);
    }
```